# Getting error messages from gmail api batch request

Tags: error-handling, google-api-php-client, gmail-api

I am trying to get gmail attachments using batch requests on the gmail API. It sometimes works, but if I rerun it, I'll get errors a large percentage of the time. I'd like to catch the errors and take appropriate action - like exponential backoff, which will (hopefully) fix the problem. But it's not working.

Here is the code:

```
for ($n = 0; $n < 5; ++$n) {
    try {
      $results = $batch->execute();
      break;
    } catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
      if ($e->getError() != '') { //placeholder
        // Apply exponential backoff.
        usleep((1 << $n) * 1000 + rand(0, 1000));
      } 
    }
  }


  for ($i=1; $i < $stop+1; $i++) {
    $message = $results['response-'.$i];
            if ($message2->getPayload()) { ...
```

The error logs show that sometimes I'm immediately trying to call Google_Service_Exception::getPayload. It's as if each response in the batch was itself a Google_Service_Exception object, or at least the first one.

How do I catch errors in a batch?

Comment: I imagine this is ruby?  :-)

Comment: It's php. I found something that says that, instead of throwing an exception, batch responses return the errors within the results. Thus I have rewritten the the code to check what class is returned for each result and to take action that way. I wish the libraries gave an option as to how batch errors were handled. For example, I would like to call batch->execute with the option of retrying using exponential backoff for n number of times if the results are being rate limited.

Comment: seems like a useful thing to have (in the php client library).  will adjust flags so the folks that care about that tag can chime in.